# Regex pattern concatenation

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, concatenation

Is it possible to somehow concatenate this:

```
my $ pattern1 = qr/^/;
```

with this:

```
my $ pattern2 = qr/ABC/
```

so I get (the value of) this?

```
qr/^ABC/
```

The syntax could be different, I just want to achieve this result.

Comment: What inputs are you trying to match?

Comment: Have you tried concatenation? Seems like your question is rather trivial, e.g. `$foo =~ /$pattern1$pattern2/` or `$pattern3 = $pattern1 . $pattern2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can concatenate regular expressions easily:

```
say /$pattern1$pattern2/ for 'ABC', 'XABC';
```

To increase readability, you can use the `/x` modifier and add a space:

```
say / $pattern1 $pattern2 /x for qw( ABC XABC );
```

Note that scalars are usually written without the space after the `$` sigil.

Comment: You could probably have a space in there with an `x` modifier on the pattern I think?

Comment: How do I concatenate a pattern in a variable with another pattern, e.g. `qr/$somePatternabcd/`. Perl parses it as a `somePatternabcd` variable instead of `somePattern` variable and `abcd` string/pattern.

Comment: @NPS: You can use `qr/${somePattern}abcd/` or `qr/$somePattern abcd/x`.